# Why do we need stdexcept header

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception

Why do we need `stdexcept`? For example `std::runtime_error`. Why do we need it? Can't I use my own try-catch blocks? If I can why people use them. Should I use them too or should I create my own try catch blocks?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b= 0, c;

    try {
        if ( b == 0 )
            throw runtime_error("divide by zero error");
        c = a/b;

        cout << c<<endl;
    } catch(runtime_error &error) {

        cout << "exception accured"<<endl;
        cout << error.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of this can't i use the code below?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 10, b= 0, c;

    try {
        if ( b == 0 ) {
            throw "divide by zero error";
        }
        c = a/b;
        cout << c << endl;
    } catch (const char *error) {
        cout << "exception accured"<<endl;
        cout << error;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which one should i use and what is the pros of `std::runtime_error` (and other `stdexcept-except` classes)

Comment: "Why do we need to use the standard things given to us when we can just reinvent the wheel and do it badly?" If you think exceptions are only about pushing error strings around you need to read more.